# Local Coordinate System

Tags: postgis-2.0, 3d

I am currently evaluating the use of PostGIS (version 2.0) for:

- a project that will store 3D coordinates (x, y, z) data
- the data will have it's own local coordinate system which does not correspond to any datum (SRID)

Question: Can this data be stored without any SRID? If so, can I still take advantage of the 3D spatial query capabilities in PostGIS?

Thanks for you time,
Craig

Comment: I wonder if you could invite your own coordinate system? Or use one that doesn't have a fixed datum>

Comment: Have a try by importing some data without giving any SRID. The default SRID=0 which means "unknown" will be used. Test what works and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default SRID in PostGIS is zero meaning unknown or local coordinate system. You can take advantage of all geometry-based queries and functions -- except any that transform or project between known coordinate systems. (Geography-based queries and functions won't make any sense.)